# Most efficient way to make an object of numbers (sizes) from an object of Sets in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that aims to take an object of strings Sets, kinds of like this :

```js
interface Input {
  userIds: Set<string>;
  companyIds: Set<string>;
  actionIds: Set<string>;
}
```

and return an object of numbers (the size of every Set), kinds of like this :

```js
interface Output {
  users: number;
  companies: number;
  actions: number;
}
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way to do that. Keep in my mind that my real `Input` and `Output` have dozens of entries and each set might have thousands of entries each.

My first, straightforward, approch, is something like this :

```js
  return {
    users: input.userIds.size,
    companies: input.companyIds.size,
    actions: input.actionIds.size,
  };
```

Comment: Sets don't have a `.length`, they have a `.size`. But other than that, it'll be really straightforward and the basic approach is the most efficient one already. Have you tried to write this function yet?

Comment: I've edited my question to answer your, useful, comment. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that works. Why do you assume it's not efficient?

Comment: I can understand that if the number of entries in your Input is too high, it can be a cause for performance drop when trying to convert one object to another. 

However I feel like this conversion is not bringing any real value, you already have the information that you need in the Input object, if you want the user count you can simply access the Input object and call userIds.size().

But if you think the conversion is really necessary, you should use the basic approach that you have posted in order to achieve the wanted result.

Comment: And to make your solution more dynamic I would suggest the following implementation:
const Output = {};

for(const inputKey of Input) {
  Output[inputKey.replace("Ids", "")] = Input[inputKey].size;
}

Comment: @Bergi : I don't know if it's efficient in terms of performance. But I'm pretty sure I can do better in terms of a) number of lines of code and b) code scalability

Comment: @ArditMirashi : I was looking for this kind of things, thank you. But Typescript throws several errors : `Type 'Input' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)` (at "of input") `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Output'.` (at "output[inputKey]")

Comment: @FE-P It's `for … in` not `for … of`, also with the general loop you'd also use a general type (`Record<string, Set<User>>` or ``Record<`${string}Ids`, Set<User>>`` etc) not your specific `Input` and `Output` ones