# Custom type extending Record but with a fixed list of keys

Tags: typescript

In order to use the functionalities of the Record type (`for...in` in this case), I want to create a custom type extending Record. But I also want my type to have a fixed list of keys, which is not the case if you simply extends Record like this :

```js
interface CustomType<T> extends Record<string, T> {
  firstKey: T;
  secondKey: T;
  thirdKey: T;
}
```

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: If you extend `Record<string, T>` then you inherit the index signature and cannot have a fixed list of keys.  Can you provide a [mre] that shows your use cases so we have something concrete to test against?  Probably you'll end up needing to widen your fixed key object to an index signature object when doing `for...in`, but I'd need to see actual code examples before I would hazard any further guesses.

Comment: I extended Record after comments on this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76736897/most-efficient-way-to-make-an-object-of-numbers-sizes-from-an-object-of-sets-i